# Access a secondary Xorg for cloud gaming

Tags: xorg, games, gpu, remote-access

How can I setup a secondary Xorg that is only accessible via a connection (like VNC or Gaming Anywhere), in a way that it is GPU accelerated (will be used via LAN)?

Comment: You could use something like x forwarding to access a specific app on the machine over SSH however by default opengl commands are forwarded directly to the client to render. This may be undesirable if the client has inferior graphics capabilities. It is however possible to have the server machine do the rendering by using something like virtualgl, I have done this to let my desktop run games from the comfort of my laptop, you can find out more details on the website http://www.virtualgl.org/ If you need the full desktop accelerated their sister project turbovnc might help, see link on site.

Comment: This could solve the GPU acceleration problem while accessing the remote computer, but how can I force X to accelerate the secondary display?

Comment: I've only tried VirtualGL personally so can't say for sure exactly how to go about setting up the accelerated 3D on TurboVNC. If you look on their website they do have a specific guide for using TurboVNC with VirtualGL to provide 3D acceleration on the server side I'd recommend starting there http://www.turbovnc.org/Documentation/UltraVNC